# Java jdbc get column names of generated keys

Tags: java, jdbc

I've inserted a record with a composite primary key in table via `jdbc` and got generated values of primary key.

```
pm = connection.prepareStatement(strQuery,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pm.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rsInsert = pm.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rsInsert != null && rsInsert.next()){
    int count = rsInsert.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 1;i <=count;i++)
    {
        Object value = rsInsert.getObject(i);
    }
}
```

How can I get the column names of generated values?
Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: Which database system? This is very implementation dependent?

Answer (score 3):

If you had examined the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) you're getting with `rsInsert.getMetaData()` you might have seen [getColumnLabel(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel%28int%29) which will return the suggested name at a given column number.

```
// You are getting the Generated Keys here.
pm = connection.prepareStatement(strQuery,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pm.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rsInsert = pm.getGeneratedKeys(); // <-- This ResultSet is from the
                                            // insert. Not a standard Query.
if(rsInsert != null && rsInsert.next()){
  int count = rsInsert.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
  for(int i = 1;i <=count;i++)
  {
    String colName = rsInsert.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i); // or ColumnName
    Object value = rsInsert.getObject(i);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Obviously, if your JDBC driver doesn't follow the Javadoc specification in [getGeneratedKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) ("Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this Statement object. If this Statement object did not generate any keys, an empty ResultSet object is returned.") then your results may differ.

Comment: This retrieves the name of the column, not the name of the generated value column.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True, but all of the columns are generated value columns when your ResultSet is `ResultSet rsInsert = pm.getGeneratedKeys();`

Comment: If that will make this work, edit your post properly to show that you should work with this `ResultSet` rather than the common result of `executeQuery`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Updated. But that was OP's code. And part of the question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not necessarily, for example Firebird and PostgreSQL JDBC drivers return all columns

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, because for firebird it is next to impossible to decide on generated columns, especially a generated primary key; and postgresql uses `INSERT ... RETURNING *` so it doesn't need to query metadata. Oracle on the other hand only returns the `ROW_ID`, leaving it up to the user to query the values they need.